# Abuse report attack on AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, attacks, abuse

An application that runs on AWS uses SES to send verification emails to new customers. An attacker signs up to the website and reports the verification email as abuse.

I'm wondering what options are to deal with this kind of attack. This causes the SES abuse metric to go up.

So far, I have identified his pattern and taken counter-measures, but this does pose the serious question of how to deal with this scenario generally.

1. Using Cloudflare's bot protection does protect from bots, but the attacker might pay someone to do this by hand.
2. Blocking whole providers like Yahoo and Verizon who do not adequately vet their customers. All attacks so far were from these providers, so permanently blacklisting might work, but I feel that this only delays the inevitable.

This kind of attack seems straightforward; I imagine it happens to many companies. And yes, due to the specific patterns, I know for a fact that it's the same person in this case.

Comment: I have no official confirmation but *suspect* a few parties (that keep their mouth shut about specifics) *do* in fact take this into account whether your email contains an [unsubscribe link](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8058) when deciding what actions to take when someone hits that "Report Junk" button.

Answer (score -2):

my 2 cents

How other mail providers address it?

1. would having user consent to email communication prior to signup , and presenting it as evidence to amazon help to offset fraud abuse report?
2. having fallback email provider might be help offest reports voulume?

Answer (score -3):

> I imagine it happens to many companies.

Correct. I see this as well. Outside of highly motivated campaigns it is drowned out in a sea of actual, legitimate, back and forth communication with real customers - and fat-fingered reports from customers who miss or misunderstand the various buttons in their webmail clients.

Detection of burst in abusive behaviour requires no technical help beyond what customer service needs (deserves to have available, imho), anyway.

> providers like Yahoo and Verizon who do not adequately vet their
> customers

You do not need to worry about the difference between report sources yourself. Amazon has been in the business for some time. They know good and well which sources of feedback are of which value in judging whether the abuse report merits any action on their side, as do most bigger players that receive varying levels of quality feedback.

> the SES abuse metric

.. is a somewhat helpful indicator, not a scary threat. It is an incomplete view into the metrics available to the service provider. And it is *always* of marginal value if calculated for senders so small that a single dedicated bad actor can significantly skew the data. (Some other big players decide to not even show you such metrics when they would not mean much due to low volume.) Depending on what support contract you have, replying to inquiries about exceeding certain thresholds with a generic "we applied mitigation #3 from your list" could be more time- and cost-effective than presenting the facts & results of your inquiry to a random support rep assigned to review your account.

> how to deal with this scenario generally

You can approach this like any other DoS vector. Someone is submitting cheap requests, and your job is to ensure they do not overwhelm your resources or your service providers. You do not need (and cannot) entirely eliminate it, but you can tune the cost to the attacker and the cost to you until the leverage is no longer threatening.

Verify if and when you need to, not as a mandatory step in establishing any relationship. Do not address a symptom (abuse metrics with 3rd parties), rather address the root cause (dysfunctional communication with your prospective customers).

You sending messages can only be exploited to the degree that Amazon cares about, if you

1. send worthless messages right when someone inputs the recipients on your page *and* you
2. send worthless messages in an order of magnitude of volume that you could not support (with real customer service people) anyway.

So do neither of those two. The second is easily done with appropriately scoped (by region, by source network, ..) rate limiting. The first deserves some explanation, as to why this is best viewed less as a *technical* problem, but rather a *procedural* problem:

If you have an excessive amount of people who sign up to your services that you do not follow up with in any meaningful way.. you got bigger problems than that the share of reported messages being noticed by email providers. The scenario where the email abuse metrics become an issue should be well beyond the point where your own business goals are an issue. Ask yourself what the relationship with newly interested parties should look like, and **move the part where you verify their email address back beyond the point where this kind of abuse is cheaper to execute than to combat**.  Remember that collecting the email address as a unique user handle without immediately establishing a strong proof of control is not much of an issue, so long as both confirmed and unconfirmed recipients are always offered [an easy way out](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8058) when you do send messages to the specified mailbox. There are a few edge cases around timeouts and duplicates, but they have all been solved before (e.g., by *Stack Exchange*). Technicalities should not distract you from focusing on the actual (business) relationship with the newcomer.

Comment: The answer doesn't address the point about SES metrics.

Comment: The deliberate abuse of non-existing email addresses to register accounts will lead to negative reputation metrics. High reputation metric causes SES account suspension. The answer doesn't address this at all.

Comment: This answer completely ignores the problem stated in the question, that of *deliberate malicious abuse* via signup emails.

Comment: SES doesn't care if messages are worthless or not. It counts bounces, ARF reports etc. If someone has a low-traffic site and sends one registration email per day then even a manual attack, like described in the question, sends the bounce rate to the sky and gets the SES account suspended.

Comment: Re: your edit, "it is drowned out in a sea of actual, legitimate, back and forth communication with real customers", that's only the case if there **is** a sea. I've got projects that see a signup once a week or so. An attack of the nature OP describes would end them.

Comment: @anx Please reread the question. There is an attacker who does this manually and on purpose. So far, he has been drowned out by genuine customers. We have a signup every minute on average. However, he has been doing this for weeks and is very persistent. His attack has a clear pattern, so we know it's one person doing this. However, he will eventually reach the SES abuse threshold even with much legitimate traffic. I feel like you're downplaying a serious issue here.

Comment: @AscendingEagle I *wish* Amazon would consider any of this a serious issue. Judging from my personal Inbox, they have yet to find a way to deal with that dude who thinks its extra funny to route the Amazon-specific phishing messages via Amazon servers.. Until your second or third account suspension you may very well just join in and not consider it such a big deal either. And punish that particular miscreant by devoting your attention in other business-critical areas instead.